# .NET get active Ethernet IPAddress

Tags: .net, ip-address, network-interface

I am looking to get the active IPAddress in .net, in this case the address associated with the Ethernet adapter.

Now I know I can get a list of IPs currently assigned to the machine using:

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
```

And I know I can get a good deal of information about my different Network Interfaces using:

```
NetworkInterface[] networks = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

I can determine which of those interfaces is my Ethernet interface using the NetworkInterfaceType enum and whether or not the interface is "Up", but I can't seem to find a way to tie this NetworkInterface to the corresponding IPAddress.  From within the NetworkInterface class I can only see how to get things like the Anycast Addresses or the Gateway Addresses, but nothing that can help me narrow down which is my Ethernet IP.

Does anyone know a way to do this, whether it be simple or complicated?

EDIT:
For instance netstat or tracert on the command line can give all active network connections.  It seems odd to me that .net would not have something similar to this it seems completely unnessary to me to parse command line result. 
Something like GetBestInterface() seems useful but it will only return on IP that has access to a given other IP.  Again, not very versatile.

If there is no other way to use C# to get active IPAdresses then so be it, I will use the command line, but it really just seems like something that a popular programming language should be able to do.  In fact, if anyone has a C++ or C solution that I could hook up to my C# app that would work as well.

Comment: What if there's more than one active ip address? Or more than one ethernet adapter?

Comment: If there are more then 1 active Ethernet adapters then I would be fine with getting all of them.

Comment: Even just a link to something that might be vaguely helpful would be great.

Answer (score 2):

So a useful statistic here is the total received bytes on a given interface.

```
NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived
```

Using this in conjunction with:

```
NetworkInterface.OperationalStatus
```

Can tell you if it is currently "Up" and if it has received packets in the past.  In the case of wireless the OperationalStatus is "Down" if it is not currently connected, but in the case of Ethernet, it remains "Up" even when no cable is plugged in.  I assume this is because a physical cable is not necessary to give an IPAddress but the problem is that I would like to know if it would be a waste of processing power to attempt to use that address due to it not being connected.

Lastly, tying that address to a network is very simple:

```
UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection ipc = NetworkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;
```

In this way, you access your specific NetworkInterface to get at its IP Addresses.  This typically returns both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.